# Mazda Bongo Friendee 2002 charging system or alternator not working after incorrectly jump-starting it

Tags: battery, mazda, charging

I incorrectly jump-started a 2002 Mazda Bongo Friendee by interchanging the negative and positive terminals and I blew the main fuse, replaced it but now the alternator or the charging system is not charging the battery.

Could I have blown the computer box when I incorrectly jumpstarted it, or did I damage the alternator?

When I drive the car it doesn't accelerate and it overheats.

Comment: There should be some type of fusible link between the alternator and battery. I'd voltage drop the wire. Also depending on what type of alternator you have there may be additional fuses on the alternator field circuit.

Comment: http://image-cdn.beforward.jp/autoparts/original/201601/351914/PASKU604741_43a4b1.jpg, its this alternator on this link